# Two custom template in angular formly where only one of them is woking

Tags: angular-formly

This is code http://jsbin.com/haluxa/6/edit

Problem is with radio button, it should work as follow, while i am clicking on yes, have to show other question with multiple checkbox. Although it is not working second template.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: http://jsbin.com/miroge/edit?html,js,output

The problem is that you're calling `setType` with two objects, rather than an array of two objects. What you're doing:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setType({
  name: 'multi-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'multi-checkbox-template.html',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
},{
  name: 'well-multi-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'well-multi-checkbox-template.html',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
});
```

What you should be doing:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setType([{
  name: 'multi-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'multi-checkbox-template.html',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
},{
  name: 'well-multi-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'well-multi-checkbox-template.html',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
}]);
```